# In AWS how to Copy file from one s3 bucket to another s3 bucket using lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have created two S3 buckets named as 'ABC' and 'XYZ'.
If i upload the file(Object) in 'ABC' bucket it should get automatically copy to 'XYZ'.

**For Above scenario i have to write a lambda function using node.js**

i am newly learning the lambda so if you provide the details steps it will be good for me.

it will be good if we can do it by web console otherwise Np.

Comment: Show your code. What are you stuck on exactly?

Comment: I suggest reading the documentation and trying something first. We aren't here to do your job for you. You need to ask a specific question about a specific problem here.

Answer (score 0):

This post should be useful to copy between buckets of same region, https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/content-replication-using-aws-lambda-and-amazon-s3/

Answer (score -1):

If the usecase you are trying to achieve is for DR purpose in another region, you may use this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cross-region-replication-for-amazon-s3/. S3 natively does the replication for you but it's unclear if that is in same region or different region from your question